# How to get build status from GitLab CI?

Tags: gitlab

I want to add in cap deploy scenario checking build status from `GitLab CI`.

Is it possible?

Does `GitLab CI` has some API to get build/pipeline status by commit `SHA`?

Comment: I haven't found any good documentation on their build badge URLs.  If anyone has a link please post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found such link http://some.domain/projects/:ID/builds/:SHA/status .
Problem resolved

Comment: with version GitLab CI 5.3.0 c28a8ea, the url has been changed to [http://some.domain/projects/:ID/commits/:SHA/status.json](http://some.domain/projects/:ID/commits/:SHA/status.json)

Answer (score 13):

Now you can get the badge from this url:

```
https://gitlab.com/[namespace]/[project]/badges/[branch]/pipeline.svg
```

Answer (score 9):

[GitLab CI](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci) is based on [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/), which provide [build status url](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/status-images/) and even build status picture:

```
https://travis-ci.org/[YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME]/[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME].png
# or, limited to some branches
https://travis-ci.org/[YOUR_GITHUB_USERNAME]/[YOUR_PROJECT_NAME].png?branch=master,staging,production
```

[Joran Beasley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541038/joran-beasley) mentions the url:

```
http://gitlabci.example.com/projects/2/status.png?ref=master
```

Comment: Their documentation is pretty bad on this.  Joran's URL above does work.

Comment: @aglassman good point. I have included Joran's comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the build badge information on the *Pipelines settings* page, that is

```
https://<your-gitlab-installation-domain>/<group-name>/<repository-name>/settings/ci_cd
```

For a specific repository:

1. go to **Settings** > **CI / CD**
2. expand the **General pipelines settings** section
3. scroll down to **Pipeline status** and/or **Coverage report**
4. select your branch
5. copy whatever you need (Markdown, perhaps)

For reference, see:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html#badges
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html

Answer (score 1):

## API

Since GitLab 8.1, there is the new commit status API.

[GitLab CI Commits API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html) v4:

[List the statuses of a commit](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-the-statuses-of-a-commit)

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/17/repository/commits/18f3e63d05582537db6d183d9d557be09e1f90c8/statuses
```

P.s. GitLabs tokens are being managed in the [Personal Access Tokens](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens)  page (`https://gitlab.example.com/profile/personal_access_tokens`)

## `glab` and `lab`

There are two great tools to work with `GitLab`:

- [zaquestion/lab: Lab wraps Git or Hub, making it simple to clone, fork, and interact with repositories on GitLab](https://github.com/zaquestion/lab)
  [profclems/glab: An open-source GitLab command line tool bringing GitLab's cool features to your command line](https://github.com/profclems/glab)

> Both [glab](https://github.com/profclems/glab) and `lab` are open-source tools with the same goal of bringing GitLab to your command line and simplifying the developer workflow. In many ways `lab` is to [hub](https://github.com/github/hub), what [glab](https://github.com/profclems/glab) is to [gh](https://github.com/cli/cli).
>
> `lab` aims to feel familiar to a `git` user and leverages `git` to power many of it's commands. `glab` will feel more familiar to `gh` users and in turn is more interactive and likely more beginner friendly for that reason.

### `lab ci status`

For textual representation of a CI pipeline with `lab` you may want:

```
lab ci status [branch] [flags]
```

#### Examples

```
lab ci status
lab ci status upstream 608 --merge-request
lab ci status 600 --wait
lab ci status upstream 125 --merge-request --bridge 'security-tests'
```

### `glab pipeline status`

For textual representation of a CI pipeline with [`glab`](https://glab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline/status.html) you may want:

`glab pipeline status \[flags\]`

### Examples

```
$ glab pipeline status --live
$ glab pipeline status --branch=master   // Get pipeline for master branch
$ glab pipe status   // Get pipeline for current branch
```