# How to get the pipeline status from GitLab with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'am currently trying to get the status of a GitLab job with Javascript on GitLab Pages.

I have tried the following but I always receive an error 404 not found.

```
fetch('https://gitlab.devops.telekom.de/api/v4/projects/165107/jobs', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'TOKEN'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ "id": 78912 })
  }).then(response => response.json()).then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response)));
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341918/how-to-get-build-status-from-gitlab-ci

Comment: If that's a real private token, you may want to consider rotating it ASAP.

Comment: The token was revoked before posting this question, but I should have replaced it nonetheless, thanks.